# CSV to JSON using loop

Tags: python, json, csv

I wrote a program to convert CSV to JSON. I wrote the same code again and again for each column.

```
import csv, json
from os import read

#--------- COLUMN-1------------#
with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)    
    data0 = {
        "Enabled": True,
        "Stops": []
        }
    for row in reader:
       data0["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[0]})

#--------- COLUMN-2------------#
with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data1 = {
        "Enabled": True,
        "Stops": []
        }
    for row in reader:
       data1["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[1]})

#--------- COLUMN-3------------#
with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data2 = {
        "Enabled": True,
        "Stops": []
        }
    for row in reader:
       data2["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[2]})

#--------- COLUMN-4------------#
with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data3 = {
        "Enabled": True,
        "Stops": []
        }
    for row in reader:
       data3["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[3]})

#--------- COLUMN-5------------#
with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    data4 = {
        "Enabled": True,
        "Stops": []
        }
    for row in reader:
       data4["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[4]})

root = {}
root["base_strip1"] = data0
root["base_strip2"] = data1
root["base_strip3"] = data2
root["base_strip4"] = data3
root["base_strip5"] = data4

main_root = {}
main_root["ReelStripsDefinition"] = root

with open ("json1.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(main_root, f, indent=4)
```

Is there anything that can be done using **loops** to shorten this code.

CSV File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19u8M0wFrUq8E9um3l6sw0UZeQZRWTxNb/view?usp=sharing

JSON Format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FyG7gG31FzvQECx1nP0VKsd84bOQ3pOy/view?usp=sharing

Attempted Code:

```
import csv, json
from os import read

with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for data in reader:
        for i in range(5):    
            data[i] = {
                "Enabled": True,
                "Stops": []
                }
            for row in reader:
                data[i]["Stops"].append({"Symbols":row[i]})

root = {}
root["base_strip1"]
main_root = {}
main_root["ReelStripsDefinition"] = root

with open ("jsonloop.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(main_root, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: What have you researched or attempted to write the repeated code as a loop?

Comment: When I used loops, I didn't get the data in the JSON Format shared above.

**PS: All i want is to not write the same piece of code 5 times just for 5 columns**

Comment: What I meant was, have you gone through the Python tutorial? Please go through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) first and make an effort in creating a loop before asking a question with your code showing your attempt if you are still stuck.

Comment: I did tried it, but couldn't get the results. If you find it hard to believe I can add my attempted code.

Comment: Yes please, as showing your non-working code is the only way we can see where you might be stuck and help.

Comment: Any update on this? @blhsing

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you share a subset of `newsample2.csv` and the expected json?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
import csv, json
from os import read

with open ("newsample2.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)    
    
    data = [{"Enabled": True, "Stops" : []} for _ in range(5)]
    
    for row in reader:
        for col in range(5):
            data[col]["Stops"].append({"Symbols" : row[col]})

main_root = {"ReelStripsDefinition" : {f"base_strip{bs}" : item for bs, item in enumerate(data, start=1)}}

with open ("json1.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(main_root, f, indent=4)
```

The trick is to use lists instead of specific variable names.